# Flutter icon not working, even when I followed the format for previous children

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some weird behavior with my flutter code. I had a `Wrap` of these 5 widgets, copy pasted one more child, with `Icons.create` and for some reason the icon doesn't display on my last child. I've ran `flutter clean` and rebuilt my project, restarted the app, and made sure `uses-material-design: true` is on my `pubspec.yaml` file. Here is code for my last 2 children in my `Wrap` widget.

If I changed the icon to any icon of my previous existing children such as `Icons.camera_alt` the icon will display correctly, the problem only persists when I try use an icon that I haven't used in my previous children.

My previous children were made a while ago, and only started adding this widget today where the problem arose, I'm pretty sure this wasn't a problem before when I made the previous children. Anything I might have overseen causing this issue?

I am running this code on flutter web via Google Chrome.

```
            widget.currentPage == "View Selfies"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.camera_alt, // WORKING ICON
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "View Selfies",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewSelfies()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.camera_alt, // WORKING ICON
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "View Selfies",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),
            // inside Wrap's children list

            widget.currentPage == "Reminder Options"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.create, // PROBLEM ICON
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Reminder Options",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => AdminOptionsPage()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.create, // PROBLEM ICON
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Reminder Options",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image: Obtained results]

This is my full `Wrap` widget.

```
child: Wrap(
          spacing: 25,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            // top gap
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            ),
            //menu1
            widget.currentPage == "One-Time Password"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.key,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "One-Time Password",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.key,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "One-Time Password",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu2
            widget.currentPage == "Employee Logs"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.person,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Employee Logs",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmployeeLogs()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Employee Logs",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu3
            widget.currentPage == "Upload Batches"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.upload,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Upload Batches",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UploadBatches()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.upload,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Upload Batches",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu4
            widget.currentPage == "View Batches"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.stacked_bar_chart,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "View Batches",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewBatches()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.stacked_bar_chart,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "View Batches",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu5
            widget.currentPage == "Create New User"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.add,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Create A New User",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => CreateNewUser()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Create A New User",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu6
            widget.currentPage == "Assign Users"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.group_add_rounded,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Assign Users",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AssignUsers()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.group_add_rounded,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Assign Users",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),

            //menu7
            widget.currentPage == "View Selfies"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        // <-- TextButton
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "View Selfies",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    // <-- TextButton
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewSelfies()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "View Selfies",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),
            // inside Wrap's children list
//menu8
            widget.currentPage == "Reminder Options"
                ? Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 241, 239)),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextButton.icon(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // DO NOTHING YOU'RE ALREADY ON THE PAGE
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          color:
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34).withOpacity(0.5),
                          Icons.create,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Reminder Options",
                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)
                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => AdminOptionsPage()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34),
                      Icons.create,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    label: Text(
                      "Reminder Options",
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 19, 34)),
                    ),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
```

**UPDATE**

The issue still persists, but I realise I can view all my icons when I run in release or profile mode, but the ordinary `flutter run` will always fail to show some icons.

Comment: i just run code in my chrome it showing both the icons, only icon not show or both the icon and the text "View Selfies" also?

Comment: Only the icon for my Icons.create. I am unsure why. I have edited my question to show what's happening on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code but all the icons are displayed correctly. Maybe it depends on the version of Flutter.

I am using:
Dart SDK - 2.19.6
Flutter SDK - 3.7.12

Also, for **flutter web**, it is better to use the rendering setting `--web-renderer='html'`. By default, `--web-renderer='auto'` is the same as `--web-renderer='canvaskit'`.
However, I tested the display of icons using both methods and they were displayed correctly.

[image: All icons are displayed correctly.]

Comment: This is odd, I have tried adding more icons, and they wouldn't show up when ran locally, but show up on deployment. 
Dart SDK version: 3.0.0 (stable) (Thu May 4 01:11:00 2023 -0700) on "windows_x64" Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable • github.com/flutter/flutter.git 

I have ran ``flutter clean`` and ``flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`` it still doesn't show.